# Are spans of orbits pairwise disjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space, $A \in \operatorname{Aut}(V)$. Then $k \mapsto A^k$ defines a group action of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ on the underlying set of $V$. The orbits of the action are pairwise disjoint. Let $\mathbb{Z}u \neq \mathbb{Z}v$. Does it follow that $\operatorname{span} \, \mathbb{Z}u \cap \operatorname{span} \, \mathbb{Z} v = 0$?

Edit: I screwed up and wrote $\neq$ instead of $=$. My apologies to @anon :(

I need a hint, not a full answer (unless the answer requires some really advanced math).

Comment: Just a general comment.  For this type of question, I would look at examples, starting with the easiest, stupidest ones and getting progressively more sophisticated.

Comment: What do you really want to ask? "Do spans of orbits necessarily have trivial intersection?" or "Do spans of orbits necessarily have nontrivial intersections?" Title and question text seem to aim in opposite directions ... @anon gave a negative answer to the second question (as in the question text), I gave a negative answer to th efirst question (as nearly in the title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $u$ select $v\in\operatorname{span}(\mathbb Z u)\setminus\mathbb Zu$. Then $\mathbb Zv \cap \mathbb Zu=\emptyset$, but $\operatorname{span}(\mathbb Z v)\subseteq \operatorname{span}(\mathbb Z u)$. For the other extreme see anon's answer.

Comment: At least if $A\ne 0$, we can conclude $A\cap B\ne 0$. Such choice of $v$ is possible at least if the base field is $\mathbb R$. Then again, after rereading the question carefully, it seems that *your* answer answers the question (as posed) correctly. (I answered the question I had expected instead: Does it follow that the span of distinct orbits is the zero subspace?)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at. :-) [Hmm, I hadn't even noticed the discrepancy with the title.]

Answer (score 2):

Consider $V=U_1\oplus U_2$ and $A=A_1\oplus A_2$ with $u\in U_1\oplus 0$ and $v\in 0\oplus U_2$ (each nonzero).

Okay, for the updated question, how about something geometric? Say, a $90^\circ$ rotation in the plane, and vectors $u$ and $v$ of different magnitudes. Note that each orbit will span the entire space.

Comment: If it's a counterexample, I don't get it :(

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko It is a counterexample. How can the spans of $\Bbb Zu$ and $\Bbb Zv$ intersect nontrivially if everything in $\langle\Bbb Zu\rangle$ has vanishing second coordinate and everything in $\langle\Bbb Zv\rangle$ has vanishing first coordinate? (They can't!)

Comment: Oh shi-${}{}{}{}$